# Ideas on how to make user-defined variables within a Java program?

Tags: java, variables, user-defined

I am new in Stack Exchange, and I have been looking around for quite a while, with no answer. In my free time I am creating a matlab/like program in Java, I have noticed that I need to create a way of allowing the user to create its own variables from within the program. An example would be a = 5 and b = 3, and so when a + b = 8. 
My first idea was to create a folder, where files can be saved as variables and then searched when the user calls for a particular variable. Any kind of feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can create a groovy DSL and have your java classes compile it at runtime.  http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-running-groovy-scripts.html

Comment: Are you trying to create a parser?

Comment: How will they be "asking" for it? What will you do with them? Sounds more like you're implementing a language (because you are)--how best to do that depends on several factors. You might look in to the standard Java scripting APIs first, though.

Comment: I was thinking of creating something similar to a mathematical program, maybe like a parser as A.R.S. suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you could do this using Map

```
Map<String, Integer> nameToValueMap
```

- Ask user about name and put its value into map
- Ask user to add two variables (lets say A, B) , fetch the associated values from map and manipulate it

Comment: Thank you lots for the recommendation, I was thinking of something similar to that, you pointed exactly to what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
    Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //add a variable
    variables.put("a", 5);
    variables.put("b", 3)'
    //get value of variable
    int a = variables.get("a");
    int b = variables.get("b");
    int output = a + b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of Properties file. You can find more info and some examples [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/props.html)
They are really simple to read and write, and allow you to customize value of variables changing files. They have the advantage that you can keep all variable in a single file, simplifying your deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a `Map<String,Variable>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to implement a scripting language in Java. You could use one of the languages already available (e.g.: [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Javascript](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)), or create your application in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), instead.

See also:

[Scripting for the Java platform](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223)
[Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.util.Map<String, Object>` to store them